# updating date in MS Access using Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ms-access, jdbctemplate

I'm using MS Access and Spring Jbdc Template.

Where If I try to update the date in table using jdbctemplate it giving me error

```
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement."
```

This is the code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime());

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
int id = jdbcTemplate
   .queryForInt("select TASK_ID from timesheet where task_id=1");
jdbcTemplate.update("update timesheet set date=? where task_id=20",
                     new Object[] { sqlDate });
```

Thanks in Advance,
Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is a keyword in Jet (the Access db engine) so it needs to be "escaped" with square brackets.  Also, date literals are delimited by `#`'s.  I'm not familiar enough with Java to know if your date is being formatted that way.

In any case, your sql string needs to be something like this:

```
"update timesheet set [date]=#4/5/2011# where task_id=20"
```